# Winsock closesocket() performance (local computer, 127.0.0.1): Why is it so slow on some computers and ultra fast with others?

Tags: c#, database, performance, sockets, winsock

I'm struggling with an odd performance problem related to closing database connections in my C# code. We are using a database server called Raima on a local computer (only local TCP connection 127.0.0.1 to the local database server on the same computer, not across a LAN) via its native Raima API (not ADO.NET, just a .NET wrapper).

The problem is that on many computers (high-performance dual-core or quad-core computers) the closing takes about 120ms-250ms most of the time (e.g. 120ms in a .NET C# web service and 250ms in a .NET C# Windows application) while on the other computers it takes only 4ms (steady). What confuses me is that on some computers it's, for example, 120ms most of the time, but occasionally it may jump to 4ms.

Our database vendor (Raima) has told us that they can't do anything about it because these slowdowns are caused by the Winsock method closesocket().

So my question is that is it true that Winsock closesocket() may cause these kinds of slowdowns on a local computer? Or is it, after all, just about the database vendor and their slow database driver/server?

Thanks!

Comment: there is no general answer to that BUT the performance definitely depends on several aspect like the NIC drivers, Windows version, empty/full TCP/IP buffers, some NIC-/TCP-related registry setting  etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you test your raima (you call it) using performance tools / stress tess tools; test your network using networking tools; install your computer using other database (free edition of SQL server, IBM DB2, MySQL, Oracle and others) and try to connect it and count its performance.
AFAIK it is not winsock implementation, it is computer configuration. If all database is slowdown so you can suspect of winsock.
If all is slow, perhaps you can mention to upgrade hardware.
If all except raima is fast. you can suspect raima database is slow.
If you have difficulty on connection like disconnection as always, just change your LAN cable.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Jason from [Raima](http://www.raima.com/).  Hopefully you received our email about this problem back in 2011, but for anyone else who has experienced this performance problem, we will explain how this was fixed:

The performance problem was in closesocket(), and explained that we could not do anything about this. Immediately afterwards one of our engineers found that we were using the SO_LINGER option, which causes closesocket() to block till all outstanding data has been sent before returning. We removed this option and sent a patch on October 11, 2011. With SO_LINGER turned off, the closesocket() function will still send outstanding data before closing the socket, but it may return before this operation is complete. The patch improved performance in most cases.

Comment: Hey, just a tip, but why not add your name (Jason) to your profile so that your user card says "Jason" rather than "user1272893"?  (would look more professional)  (I've seen you post a bunch of answers on behalf of your company, so I thought I'd point it out)